# How do I tab to a non-standard element while unit-testing for keyboard accessibility?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, accessibility, react-testing-library

### Background

I have a React/TypeScript project that I test with Jest and React Testing Library (RTL). I have one passing test that tests keyboard accessibility with RTL's `userEvent.tab()` by tabbing to a button.

```
  test('that the button is keyboard accessible', () => {
    // Arrange
    const page = render(<BrowserRouter><Page/></BrowserRouter>).container;
    const button: HTMLElement = within(page).getByText('Form button');

    // Act
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      userEvent.tab();
    }
    
    // Assert
    expect(button).toHaveFocus();
  });
```

### Problem

I have another similar keyboard accessibility test that fails:

```
  test('that My button is keyboard accessible', () => {
    // Arrange
    const nextPage: HTMLElement = render(<NextPage />).container;
    const button = screen.getByText('My button');

    // Act
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      userEvent.tab();
    }

    // Assert
    expect(button).toHaveFocus();
  });
```

The error:

```
Expected element with focus:
      <my-button>My button</my-button> // Note: `<my-button>` is a button component specific to the design system my company uses.
    Received element with focus:
      <body><div><div class="nextPage">... more tags here...<div class="bodyButtons"><my-button>My button</my-button></div></div></div></div></body>
```

No matter how many times I `userEvent.tab()`, the received element with focus is always `<body>`. I assume this is due to attempting to target a non-standard button (`<my-button>`) that is part of my company's design system.

### Question

**How do I keyboard to the Account button on this page with my unit test?** Keyboarding on the deployed app works just fine.

### Things I've tried

- `within` per the first unit test
- Changing the number of `userEvent.tab()`s from 0 to 1 to 2 to 5 to 10
- `fireEvent` instead of `userEvent`
- Rendering the component without the container
- Initially using `button.focus()` before tabbing, but I can't focus the button either
- Changing `<my-button>` to `<button>` to use a standard HTML tag
- Getting the button with `querySelector('my-button')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I keyboard to the Account button on this page with my unit test?

### Solution

I gave `<my-button>` the `tabindex=0` attribute. This made the button programmatically focusable.

The product code:

```
<my-button onClick={handleClick} tabIndex='0'>My button</my-button>
```

The test:

```
  test('that My button is keyboard accessible', () => {
    // Arrange
    render(<NextPage/>);
    const button: HTMLElement = screen.getByText('My button');

    // Act
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      userEvent.tab();
    }

    // Assert
    expect(button).toHaveFocus();
  });
```

More info from [MDN on `tabIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)